# What is the car on the cover of Top Gear/Top Racer?

Tags: top-gear, top-gear-2

What is the car on the cover of Top Gear/Top Racer game?

The same car appears to be the cover for Top Gear 2/Top Racer 2, both for SNES and Genesis versions.

If it is fictitious, what car it was probably based on?

Edit: This is the game's cover art.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1984 Corvette GTP (based on a Lola chassis) from the IMSA GTP Championship.[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Wow, that is the closest match so far. Even the livery is similar.

Answer (score 3):

I guess it's based on this type of cars:[image: a car]
[image: another car]

Don't know the name of them in English *(translator doesn't help either)* but you can google them by "**barquetas de carreras**"

*ADDING LE MANS CARS AS SUGGESTED BY @Kaizerwolf*
[image]

Comment: It would seem to be a version of a classic GT or "Le Mans" car.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf right, added to my answer :)

Comment: Nice, those Le Mans are more similar. This means the car on the cover is fictitious?

Comment: @Hydren I would say so. It's highly based on the type of cars shown tho.

Comment: @Hydren I would have to agree with Alex. It's likely it's based off the cars in the answer, but not real. If it is real, it's probably a one of a kind car which makes it very difficult to find a definite answer.

Comment: Any names for those cars, by the way? A friend of mine said it looked like a Sauber C9.

Comment: So far: **Le Mans cars** and **barquetas** as stated in my answer but almost all *classic racing cars* are like that.

Answer (score -2):

Is based on Maxda 78D, fictional car

Comment: Could you provide a source, or at least a picture of the car you mention?